# Apache редирект .htaccess с конца ссылки на .html

Tags: .htaccess, apache, редирект

Помогите составить редирект который работал бы так:

При переходе по ссылке выида `http://site.ru/novosti/{переменная1}/{переменная2}`
должно произойти перебрасывание на
`http://site.ru/novosti/{переменная1}/{переменная2}.html`
пробовал решенить так: 
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/novosti/(.*)/(.*)/$ http://site.ru/novosti/$1/$2.html`
 но этот код работает только если был на конце слеш, если его не было условие не работает, а если записать условие так: 
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/novosti/(.*)/(.*)$ http://site.ru/novosti/$1/$2.html`
 то получаю переход по адресу: 
`http://site.ru/novosti/{переменная1}/{переменная2}.html.html.hrml.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html`

как будет правильно выглядеть запись? что бы на конце обрубить непонятные лишние .html

**UPDATE**

содержимое .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

php_value max_input_vars 10000
php_value pcre.recursion_limit 1000


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]




<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
    php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

    #php_value display_errors 1

    php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
    php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+\.html$
    RewriteRule ^novosti/(.*)/(.*)$ /novosti/$1/$2.html [R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: с RedirectMatch не умею а с Modrewrite написал ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так. Первая строка, чтобы не было зацикливания

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+\.html$
RewriteRule ^novosti/(.*)/(.*)$ /novosti/$1/$2.html [R=301]
```

Comment: попробовал, вообще не каких результатов (404 ошибка) при открытии ссылки `http://site.ru/novosti/tema/novost` но документ существует по адресу: `http://site.ru/novosti/tema/novost.html`

Comment: для начала идем сюда - http://htaccess.mwl.be/ , убеждаемся, что логика правильная. А дальше надо понять, что там еще в вашем htaccess'e есть

Comment: привел `.htaccess` в шапке темы

Comment: ругается на строчку `^novosti/(.*)/(.*)$ /novosti/$1/$2.html [R=301]`

Comment: а как ру8гается?

Comment: `1 ^novosti/(.*)/(.*)$ /novosti/$1/$2.html [R=301] This line is not supported by our tool.` по вашей ссылке перешел и вставил туда свой `.htaccess`

Comment: товарищ помогите =)

Comment: что происходит с вашим htacces'om я не очень понимаю, а вот как вы ошибку на тестере получили - непонятно  http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=4d85caf5ac471ae872b244215404b8b1

Comment: http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=422c5586c1990889d650629996465fa3 вот с этим условием почему то не работает, как поправить?